# Text file busy when I copy some files

Tags: linux, cp, shared-library

I have this error when I want to copy some files

***My command:***

```
cp -rf  /sasech/xgedff/pur/liv/v15h30050-DLIV0177521/dmesa/bin/* /applis/rgedff/pur/bin
```

***Results:***

```
cp: /applis/rgedff/pur/bin/../bin/lib/libtiny.a: Text file busy
...
```

How do I copy my files ?

Comment: Could you please list the command you copy with?

Comment: `Text file busy` is shown because some other process is accessing it. `lsof` will show you what's accessing the file.

Comment: @garethTheRed `lsof` list me a lot of process

Comment: @UVV i have edit my post with the command

Comment: `lsof | grep libtiny` should limit the list.

Comment: `cp -f` should work, as it will replace the file if it can't overwrite it.

Comment: `cp -f` is not safe as it may result in removed/missing files when you are done. Better use `star` with the option `-install` at the extract side as this will first unpack the new file under a random name and then finally replace the old file by the new one by calling the atomic `rename()`. This also applies if you are using the original AT&T cpio by default or when star emulates cpio, but not to the GNU cpio clone.

Comment: @Mercer, you should remove the `/shared-library` tag since a `.a` file is a static library file, not shared.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this happen to me when I was copying files from one hard drive to another through a connection such as NFS or an SSH tunnel.

What happens is that the file being copied becomes part of the destination directory. That means the destination directory needs to be locked, updated with the new information, and then unlocked.

If the next file (which in your case would be `libtiny.a`) arrives too soon, it tries to lock the directory and fails with the "File busy" error. That then prevents the copy of that file and anything further.

Since `libtiny.a` is a static library, there are no reasons why it would ever be locked against a copy. As far as I know, the compiler does not lock the files it is working on, and really it would only happen if you were compiling something in the target directories...

Now this is assuming that all the disks use a *normal* file system. If you used NTFS, then files cannot be replaced while opened because that system does not allow for such to happen.

Under Linux, opening a file locks that file's data in place, but it does not prevent you from unlinking it, renaming it, replacing it. If the file was deleted, the locked data will be released from the hard drive once all the handles to that file get closed.

This means you can write a program which, when it gets executed, deletes itself from the hard drive and yet it will continue to function as if nothing had happened.

Comment: I received this same error while trying to do a build inside a virtual machine, with the build directory shared (mounted as a vboxsf filesystem) from the host Windows PC.

The solution was to do the build on the virtual machine's disk. I had no problems after that.

Comment: @user60561 Yes, if the host is MS-Windows, then you are using NTFS and that uses hard locks.

Comment: thanks a lot! adding some `sleep 5` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

try

```
rm -f /applis/rgedff/pur/bin/lib/libtiny.old
mv /applis/rgedff/pur/bin/lib/libtiny.a  applis/rgedff/pur/bin/lib/libtiny.old
```

before copying, be aware that you may disrupt any program that use `/applis/rgedff/pur/bin/lib/libtiny.a`

`libtiny.a` is a share library, active running program are using it, and you can't delete file being used in Linux.

More precisely, deleting such file will result in removing filename from directory, while file data will be kept in filesystem as long as a running process use them.

Comment: @mercer path above to be replace by your actual paths.

Comment: Because your proposal is risky, I recommend to use `star -copy -p -install`.

Comment: Actually, on Linux, you can delete files that are being executed. What you can't do is overwrite them.

Comment: `libtiny.a` is a static library, it would be a problem to overwrite it only if there is a compiler currently linking and having that file opened and locked.